# Table recursive relationship-query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

[image]

The above table has recursive relationship ie. the `crfor` column has reference to `resourceid` column.

So the number  `1` in the `crfor` column means `resourceid = 1` .How should I change my query to make `crforname` column (dynamic column) display the proper name `Arjun` instead of `Ashok`?

I used the query below to get the result above. You can ignore the other table call PCR in the query

```
select t1.*,t2.pcrname,t1.ResourceName AS crforName from 
Resource t1 left join Pcr t2  on t1.Pcrid=t2.pcrid   
where t1.contractid=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a self join on the `Resource` table joining the `ResourceId` to the `CrFor`:

```
select t1.*,t2.pcrname,t3.ResourceName AS crforName from 
Resource t1 left join Pcr t2  on t1.Pcrid=t2.pcrid left join Resource t3 on t1.CrFor = t3.ResourceId
where t1.contractid=1
```